# Invalid maximum heap size: -XX:MaxHeapSize=4096m

Tags: java, unreal-4, unreal, mobile

I am trying to package android project in UE4.27. And getting this

[image]

I tried changing environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M not worked.

[image]

Where can I change MaxHeapSize, please tell me exact location. Or any solution is there?

Comment: Please post code & error messages as formatted text rather than screenshots. Doing so makes it significantly easier for others to help read & research your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a 32 bit version of Java (because if it was a 64 bit version it would [explicitly say so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43454795/950488)).

The problem is that the 32 bit version [doesn't support heaps larger than 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968884/950488). You are asking for a heap twice that size.

You can solve this problem by either reducing your heap size or switching to a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: *Low effort questions tend to attract down votes*. I put together using the very first result I found when searching for "java invalid maximum heap size". If you encounter an unfamiliar error, *try dropping the error text into a web search* (part of why text is preferred to screenshots). If that doesn't lead to anything helpful, *explain what you tried in your question post*.

Comment: I was indeed using 32 bit version of java so I changed it, and I didn't get the same error. I couldn't package my project but it's irrelevant to current question. so I am accepting this as answer.